# Rewrite module, cannot match the dot character?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a site using Apache rewrite module. The problem is that I'm using the RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p1=$1 [L]
```

I need to match all the characters except "/", but it doesn't work. It counter an error "The requested URL was not found on this server."

it work with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?p1=$1 [L]
```

but this rule will not match the "dot", so whenever the url have the "dot" it will counter the same as above.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p1=$1 [L]
```

The reason that isn't working is because there is an internal redirect loop, let's say you are getting a request `/zoo`:

1. `zoo` (no leading slash here) matches `^([^/]+)/?$` and the url gets rewritten to `/index.php?p1=zoo`
2. `zoo` and `/index.php` are different so it gets internally redirected, and the rules are applied again, leading slash stripped
3. `index.php` matches `^([^/]+)/?$`, gets rewritten to `/index.php?p1=index.php`
4. `index.php` and `/index.php` are different, so internal redirect again
5. repeat 3 and 4

One way you can stop the loop is to change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1 [L]
```

So that `index.php` would match `index.php` (no leading slash), but a better way would be to add some rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

In front of the rewrite rule.

Comment: yes !! it works, but there is still an error when loading css or javascript file. it loads the home page instead of the files.

Comment: Where are your css/js files at? Are they linked with relative links?

Comment: my css is look like this `<link href="http://example.com/templates/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` what wrong with this?

Comment: That should be fine, they shouldn't be rewritten, maybe try adding this to the top of the rewrite conditions? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$`

Comment: it doesn't work, is there any problem? it seems that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` this line doesn't work with css and js files. but it works for image file `http://example.com/uploads/profiles/p55x55/sample.png`